# How do I get all the post tags in WordPress with hyperlinks and columns?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can we add tag links using this code? And maybe put it in column like 4 columns and then each column will have 15 tag links?

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags(array(
  'hide_empty' => false
));
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $post;
foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag)
{
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag_id); ?>">tag name</a>
```

Comment: So sorry how can I insert that with the php code I have used above? Thank you very much for your answer.